# Is there a way to get my other account back?

Tags: support, user-accounts

About an hour ago I was feeling pretty sad that my questions were getting closed and downvotes, and that I had a 7 day suspension. Michael Kjörling edited my question every time I tried to destroy it, so thanks. I never registered, so my question is: can I get my old account back?

Comment: [Click here for directions to recover the old account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/i-lost-control-of-my-account-before-registering-can-it-be-recovered).  Obviously, it's a big deal, so please be patient.

Comment: One thing to remember is that questions and answers here are meant to serve posterity; there is a certain standard of quality which many users hold to the content here.  If you've ever see Yahoo! Answers, you know how things work with a much looser standard (or lack thereof… to each their own, I suppose).  Worldbuilding has a “Sandbox” for users to tentatively prepare questions off the main site, but the only facility most Stack Exchange sites have to hide posts from public view involves downvoting and deleting.  Meta Stack Exchange is broken; little hope proposing any changes there …

Comment: Robert, glad to see you came back.  As others mentioned (and Monica below in her answer) SE can be frustrating while you are getting used to the site.  As a matter of fact I am pretty sure at one point Monica told me to chill out early on in the life of this site...so I can relate. :)  Users here are helpful people, they may not always be tactful but no one here is paid to help out, we do it because we like the challenge.  Good luck and feel free to ask questions.

Comment: @James: Yeah, you’re right

Answer (score 11):

You can ask Stack Exchange to [merge your two accounts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  They will confirm that you own the other account, probably by sending email or maybe by asking you to provide information that only the account owner would know.  You should also [register](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) this account so that you will not be dependent on a browser cookie for access.

You are not suspended.  You encountered an automatic, temporary question block that's built into the system to slow people down before they dig themselves into too deep a hole.  Sometimes new users have a bit of a rough start on Stack Exchange because our Q&A format is very different from discussion forums.  It happens; please don't sweat it.  Let's focus on how to move forward so you can get answers to your questions and participate in our community.

One of your questions has been edited and is on the way to being reopened.  That's the point of putting questions on hold -- not to shut them down forever, but to prevent answers from coming in while you and the community are fixing the question so it fits our site.  When you edit, experienced users review the changes and can cast reopen votes.  This takes some time, though, because people are spread all across the world and its time zones, so please be patient.

Fixing the issues with a question so it can be reopened not only gets you answers, but usually gets you upvotes which give you reputation.  Earning reputation also counters the automatic block you encountered.  When a question runs into trouble please *don't* ask it again in a new question; that actually makes things worse.  Editing is built into the system and is the way to address issues brought up by the community in comments.